# Find the midpoint of a LogisticRegression by Scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, logistic-regression

I am using Scikitlearn LogisticRegression to fit the my data like followed:

```
X = np.array([200., 201., 202., 203., 204., 205., 206., 207., 208., 209., 210.,
       211., 212., 213., 214., 215., 216., 217., 218., 219., 220., 221.,
       222., 223., 224., 225., 226., 227., 228., 229., 230., 231., 232.,
       233., 234., 235., 236., 237., 238., 239., 240., 241., 242., 243.,
       244., 245., 246., 247., 248., 249.])
y =  np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
 
clf = LogisticRegression(C=1e5, fit_intercept=True)
clf.fit(X.reshape(-1,1), y)
X_test = np.linspace(200, 250, 1000)
loss = expit(X_test * clf.coef_ + clf.intercept_).ravel()
plt. figure()
plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.plot(X_test, loss, label="Logistic Regression Model", color="red", linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

It works well, now I would like to find the midpoint of this regression, is there a simple parameter to get it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean the midpoint? What is the expected value for the y vector that you posted?

Comment: By midpoint, I mean the X value for which the fit curve equals 0.5. So for my data, I expect it to be around 219.5.

Answer (score 0):

If by midpoint you mean the value for X where the prediction is 0.5, this would be:

```py
from scipy.special import expit, logit

midpoint = (logit(0.5) - clf.intercept_) / clf.coef_
```

You can see indeed:

```py
print(midpoint)
print(expit(midpoint * clf.coef_ + clf.intercept_))
print(clf.predict_proba(midpoint))
```

Output:

```py
[[219.50002001]]
[[0.5]]
[[0.5 0.5]]
```

Note: expit(logit(p)) = p

Comment: Great, that work very well indeed! I don't get the calculation though. Could you clarify please?

Comment: You are looking for x as exp(a.x+b)=0.5. The answer is x=(ln(0.5)-b)/a. Because ln(0.5)=ax+b